# Drake Hydroelastic contact - ReadVtkToVolumeMesh: file contains a non-tetrahedron cell

Tags: drake

I'm trying to use compliant hydroelastic contact on this box in my simulation. I've defined the `compliant_hydroelastic` tag in my sdf file in the `<collision>` tag:

```
        <drake:proximity_properties>
          <drake:mu_dynamic>0.5</drake:mu_dynamic>
          <drake:mu_static>0.5</drake:mu_static>
          <drake:compliant_hydroelastic/>
          <drake:mesh_resolution_hint>0.1</drake:mesh_resolution_hint>
          <drake:hydroelastic_modulus>5e7</drake:hydroelastic_modulus>
          <drake:hunt_crossley_dissipation>1.25</drake:hunt_crossley_dissipation>
        </drake:proximity_properties>
```

And I also made tetrahedral volumetric meshes from the box's CAD files using a software I found called Gmsh. The mesh looks great to me, and Gmsh is unable to further optimize it (saying that "total badness=0", however, drake still gives an error:

```
RuntimeError: ReadVtkToVolumeMesh('/home/michaelszeng/UROP-RLRG-GCS-Box_Unloading/Codebase/data/Box_0_5_0_5_0_5.vtk', 0.001): file contains a non-tetrahedron(type id=10) cell with type id 1, dimension 0, and number of points 1
```

Does this mean the mesh is still flawed in some way? Is there a recommended way to make volumetric meshes?

Comment: The error message mentioned a cell with type id 1. It is a point instead of a tetrahedron.

This [image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kitware/vtk-examples/gh-pages/src/Testing/Baseline/Cxx/GeometricObjects/TestLinearCellDemo.png) shows which type id corresponds to which kind of cells.

If you could provide the VTK file, I can double-check in Paraview.

Comment: This Google Doc [Advice to prepare non-convex meshes for hydroelastics](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VZtVsxIjOLKvgQ8SNSrF6PtWuPW5z9PP7-dQuxfmqpc/edit?usp=sharing) might be relevant.  It will go into Hydroelastic Contact User Guide.